# Building Rotating Planes affixed to vector with angles changes from fixed frame.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Despite my attempts all day to remember how to build planes, I haven't seem to gotten to what I need.

I would like to create 3 different fixed planes to attached to a vector rotating in it's own fixed inertial frame.

To visualize:

[image]

The initial black vector **a** is a normalised vector that cannot change length, but can rotate in 3 degrees of freedom, much like an inverted 3d pendulum, it is fixed at the origin, (0,0,0) and is currently standing at (0,0,1)

The other 3 coloured vectors, **r**, **b**, **g** are respectively defined and fixed as:

**r** = {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2, 0}

**b** = {-(Sqrt[3]/2), 1/2, 0}

**g** = {0, -1, 0}

They would be described in general as:

$$\{\text{r3} \cos (\theta )-\text{r2} \sin (\theta ),\text{r2} \cos (\theta )+\text{r3} \sin (\theta ),-\text{r1}\}$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation around (0,0,1) from the fixed initial frame.

These I have obtained by dot multiplying **a** with the rotational matrix:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -\sin \left(\frac{\pi  \theta }{180}\right) & \cos \left(\frac{\pi  \theta }{180}\right) \\
 0 & \cos \left(\frac{\pi  \theta }{180}\right) & \sin \left(\frac{\pi  \theta }{180}\right) \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The reason for doing this, is that by writing a function, and simply adding any $\theta$ to my rotation matrix, I can rotate the coloured vectors along with the initial **a** vector as it rotates.

My problem now, however is that I actually only want these vectors, to use as a normal vector to describe a plane at each "end" of each vector, I need these planes to rotate with these fixed fixed vectors from the initial black vectors frame, so I can then later have 2d projects on each plane to measure angle changes.

My initial attempt was to build the parameter form of the plane as:

**x** = **r** + j (**r** x **x1**) + (**r** x **x2**) However, I realise that I'm completely unsure how I would turn this into an actual useable plane, being that I don't know either x1 or x2.

How would I build these planes properly?

Feel free to comment for clarification...it's been a while since I've done any geometry.

Here is an image drawn, to show what I intend to do, create 3 planes, to project 2d component vectors of **a** onto each. As they rotate within the initial fixed frame.

[image]

Comment: Why not characterize planes just by their normal vectors (since they pass through your fixed point)? Then just apply a rotation matrix to the matrix of unit normal vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin Mostly because I don't know how! I'd appreciate an example if you have the time :)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. The original three planes are spanned by pairs of $\mathbf r,\mathbf b,\mathbf g$? I don't understand what you've written at all. If you know the two vectors spanning the plane, their cross product will give the normal vector. (I guess unit normal isn't really necessary.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Ahh, no the planes arn't spanned by those pairs, rather, **r**, **b**,**g** should be used to create 3 new planes... please see the updated picture I drew to illustrate better ( i hope ) what I want to acheive.

Comment: Do you know that the plane that contain the origin and is orthogonal to a vector $\vec v=(a,b,c)$ has equation $ax+by+cz=0$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati mmm maybe i don’t follow, but do you mean that the red, green and blue planes i would like to create are parallel to the **z** axes, “going through the origin” but simply translated and rotated? I did not know that equation, my linear algebra is fairly weak beyond simple transformations.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand your question, you have
a vector $\vec v=(a,b,c)^T$ from the origin to the point $V=(a,b,c)$ (vectors and points are not the same thing).
A generic point of the plane $P=(x,y,z)$ is at the end of the vector $\vec p=(x,y,z)^T$ , and the vector from the point $V$ to $P$ is
$$\vec p-\vec v=
\begin{bmatrix}
x-a\\y-b\\z-c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and this vector is orthogonal to the vector $\vec v$ iff the dot product $\vec v \cdot (\vec p-\vec v)$ is null:
$$
\vec v \cdot (\vec p-\vec v)=[a,b,c]\begin{bmatrix}
x-a\\y-b\\z-c
\end{bmatrix}=0
$$

So te equation of te plane orthogonal to $\vec v$ and containing the point $V$ has equation
$$
a(x-a)+b(y-b)+c(y-c)=0
$$